# Anything to attend when changing values in a multidimensional foreach() loop?

Tags: php

I got a site that executes the following code

```
    $keywords = ($_SESSION[$_POST['ts']]);

    print_r($keywords);

    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        foreach ($keyword['whitelist'] as $entry) {
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == $entry['encoded_url']) {
                    $entry['ignore'] = $value;
                    $decodedURL = $this->base64->url_decode($entry['encoded_url']);
                    if ($value == 'noignore') {
                        echo "found!<br />";
                        $this->blacklist_model->remove($decodedURL);
                        $html = $this->analyse->getHTML($decodedURL);
                        $entry['html'] = $html[0];
                        $entry['loading_time'] = $html[1];
                    }
                    if($value == 'alwaysignore') {
                        $this->blacklist_model->add($decodedURL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($keywords);
```

The output looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/B3PtrqjB

So, as you see, there are several "found!"s in the output, so the if clause actually gets executed a few times and I expected the second array to contain new data like 'html', but, as you see, nothing changes. Is there anything to attend when changing values in multidimensional foreach() loops?

Comment: What is `$entry`? What does it contains? And which value do you want to set?

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` creates a copy of the array and loops through that. Modifying values doesn't work.

You can get around this, though, by using references.

```
foreach ($keywords as &$keyword) { 
    foreach ($keyword['whitelist'] as &$entry) { 
        foreach ($_POST as $key => &$value) { 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

With that you can modify $value and it WILL affect the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You suppose to change the Original array.
`$entry` is just an instance / unconnected node.
you need to change `$keywords`, and not its `on the fly created` nodes.